# Converting snake case string to title case

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following snake case variable `big_animal`
I want to convert it to `Big Animal`

My method is `str => str.replace(/([-_]\w)/g, g => g[1].toUpperCase());`

But I keep getting `bigAnimal`, but I want to keep the space and capitalize the first letter.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Another plain regex version:

```js
const titleCase = (s) =>
  s.replace(/^_*(.)|_+(.)/g, (s, c, d) => c ? c.toUpperCase() : ' ' + d.toUpperCase())

console .log (titleCase ('big_animal'))
console .log (titleCase ('_big_animal___with_more_Nodes'))
```

This version handles multiple consecutive underscores.  It has separate matches for the first character (or one with leading underscores) and those following a number of underscores, adding a space to the latter.

### Update

On reflection, I think it would be better to do this with two regex replaces:

```js
const titleCase = (s) =>
  s.replace (/^[-_]*(.)/, (_, c) => c.toUpperCase())       // Initial char (after -/_)
   .replace (/[-_]+(.)/g, (_, c) => ' ' + c.toUpperCase()) // First char after each -/_

console .log (titleCase ('big_animal'))
console .log (titleCase ('_big_animal___with-more--Nodes'))
```

This variant also adds handling for kebab case.

Comment: Note that this only handles underscores.  Looking at the attempt in the question, I expect that the underscores in the regex should probably be replaced with `[-_]`.  That should be a simple fix.

Comment: It may also be desirable to add `toLowerCase()` just before the initial `replace()` to make it truly titlecase. Otherwise you could potentially end up with `big_aNIMAL` and the result would be `Big ANIMAL`.

Comment: @Zei: OTOH, `'my_HTML_renderer'` would turn into `'My Html Renderer'`, which could also be problematic.  I think if that's what's desired, it might be best to call `titleCase (myString .toLowerCase())`.  But YMMV.

Comment: Good thinking. That may even be relevant in my own use-case. I'm going to need to edit my own function. I can just use regex to ignore a word when it is all caps and then apply the lowercase only to words that aren't. Probably won't be quite as smooth as your one liner though.

Comment: For the first regex-based solution, I would use the following to avoid any trailing underscore characters:
`const titleCase = (s) => s.replace(/^_*(.)|_+(.?)/g, (s, c, d) => c ? c.toUpperCase() : d ? ' ' + d.toUpperCase() : '');`

Answer (score 9):

First split the string by underscore. Then Capitalize the first letter.

```js
let str = "big_animal";

let ret = str
  .split("_")
  .filter(x => x.length > 0)
  .map((x) => (x.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + x.slice(1)))
  .join(" ");
console.log(ret);
```

Comment: Note that this would add a leading space if the first character is an underscore or if there are multiple underscores in a row.

Comment: @Scott is it okay now?

Comment: It looks so to me.  But it added enough complexity that I would probably prefer a regex version.  Still, a nice demo of the simplicity of small steps!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stick with the regex approach.

```js
let str = "big_animal_and_more"
let output = str.replace(/(^\w)/g, g => g[0].toUpperCase()).replace(/([-_]\w)/g, g => " " + g[1].toUpperCase()).trim();
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Note that this would add a leading space if the first character is an underscore or if there are multiple underscores in a row.

Comment: i didnt realize leading underscores are a thing in "snake case".  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case But if that is an issue, just use .trim() on the output.

Comment: Note that this answer also includes conversion from kebab case which more closely matches the pattern of the regex defined in the question.

Comment: Yes, I noticed the same kebab-case alternative after posting my answer and just added a comment to it rather than changing the code.

Comment: same. I updated my answer to include .trim() thanks for the observations

Answer (score 0):

Here is the type script equivalent based on above solutions

```
/**
 * String Converter to convert snake_case to Title Case
 * Eg.
 * - quick_brown_fox -> Quick Brown Fox
 * - quick_brown____fox -> Quick Brown Fox
 * - quick_brown_fox----jumps_over -> Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over
 *
 */

const convertSnakeToTitleCase = (s: string): string =>
  s
    .replace(/^[-_]*(.)/, (_, c: string) => c.toUpperCase())
    .replace(/[-_]+(.)/g, (_, c: string) => ' ' + c.toUpperCase());
```

And here is the JEST based tests

```
import { convertSnakeToTitleCase } from './helpers';

describe('convertSnakeToTitleCase helper function unit tests', () => {
  it('returns correct output for regular snake case string', () => {
    expect(convertSnakeToTitleCase('quick_brown_fox')).toBe('Quick Brown Fox');
  });

  it('returns correct output for snake case strings with consecutive underscores', () => {
    expect(convertSnakeToTitleCase('quick_brown_____fox')).toBe(
      'Quick Brown Fox'
    );
  });

  it('returns correct output for snake case strings with hyphen separated strings', () => {
    expect(convertSnakeToTitleCase('quick_brown_fox-----jumps_over')).toBe(
      'Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over'
    );
  });
});
```