# String formatting in JavaScript: item:sample_text to Sample text

Tags: javascript, typescript, string

I am trying to format a string in JavaScript as stated in the title e.g. `"item:sample_text"` to `"Sample text"`. Another example would be `"item:longer_sample_text"` to `"Longer sample text"`.

I know how to do it, but I wonder if it could be done in a more efficient or a cleaner way.

```
const stringTokens = originalString?.split(':');
if (!stringTokens) return '';
const stringToChange = stringTokens[stringTokens.length - 1];
const finalString = stringToChange[0].toUpperCase() + stringToChange.slice(1).replace('_', ' ');
```

This looks a bit ugly and I think it could be done better. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting snake case string to title case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64489395/converting-snake-case-string-to-title-case)

Answer (score 0):

A little cleaner

```
const stringToChange = stringTokens.pop()
```

Instead of

```
const stringToChange = stringTokens[stringTokens.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this by using `RegEx` with the JavaScript methods [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and [`String.replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll).

- The regex pattern is `/:(.*)/` matches the characters after `:` in a string.
- The regex pattern is `/^./` matches the first character of a string.

Live Demo **:**

```js
// Input string
const str = "item:longer_sample_text";

// Regex to get the matched sub string.
const stringToChange = str.match(/:(.*)/)[1];

// Regex to capitalize first character of a string.
const capitalized = stringToChange.replace(/^./, stringToChange[0].toUpperCase());

// final String
const finalString = capitalized.replaceAll('_', ' ');

// print the output
console.log(finalString);
```